# FileBackedOutputStream use case (Guava)

Tags: java, ftp, iostream, guava, java-io

I came across `FileBackedOutputStream` class from `Google Guava` library and was wondering if it's suitable to be used as a kind of a buffer: once every day, a process in my webapp generates tens of thousands of lines (each containing about 100characters) which are then uploaded to a file on an FTP server. I was thinking of using a `FileBackedOutputStream` object to first write all these strings to and then give access to them to my FTP client by using `FileBackedOutputStream.getSupplier().getInput()`, which returns an `InputStream`. Would this be a correct use case for `FileBackedOutputStream`?

Comment: If you want an InputStream, why not use a ByteArrayOutputStream and a ByteArrayInputStream? Its likely to be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Is that also suitable for data of the size I mentioned, i.e. tens of thousands of lines (strings), each about 100 characters long?

Comment: It's thread safe which is important when I/O resources are used. Give it a try

Comment: Give a try to ByteArrayOutputStream or FileBackedOutputStream?

Comment: Peter: BAOS is slightly more efficient, but FileBackedOutputStream was designed for efficiency: [it] starts buffering to a byte array, but switches to file buffering once the data reaches a configurable size. So you get most of both: in-memory speed for small data and huge capacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think that would be an acceptable use case for `FileBackedOutputStream`. However, I think `FileBackedOutputStream` is best when you're using it with data that may vary in size considerably... for small amounts of data that can fit in memory without a problem you want to just buffer them in memory but for large amounts of data that might give you an `OutOfMemoryError` if you try to read it all in to memory, you want to switch to buffering to a file. This is where `FileBackedOutputStream` really shines I think. I've used it for buffering uploaded files that I need to do several things with.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old post, but just in case you are still using the above mentioned class, just be aware of this vulnerability, https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-2976, where files created by using the older versions might be vulnerable to attack, namely files and/or directories may be accessible to other parties (improper authorization)